# Is it possible to no-damage kill the Dagron without Monster Milk and Pike Balls?

Tags: shantae-pirates-curse

Because it seems either the timing is very tight on getting enough damage in, or something. He has 400 HP, so a running damage tally might be needed, for people to succeed

Get 200 out of a possible 280 damage in the first cycle, then deal 200 more, so it's *not* the fastest possible phase the second time, or something.

Because he gets faster as more damage is dealt, and the final speeds seem too fast to *dodge* all his attacks and instead it's just hoping a easy one to dodge is chosen?

Not sure how fast her whipping is when it's got all the cream. But I know she deals 8 HP a hair-whip hit at max. It's probably less than 200 damage a cycle, regular max.

I did two cycles and he didn't go down, but 1 Monster Milk (13 damage) + Super Pike Ball (5 damage) did it, with a few partial cycles before I got him to land...

If it's 144 HP every full cycle, then the best strat would be 120, 144, 144, assuming the "Fastest Dagron" activates at 300 HP.